# How to make VBA click a button in a different workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

Workbook 1 contains Macro 1, which I wrote.

I'm using Macro 1 to send input data to Workbook 2, and then retrieve calculations from Workbook 2. Workbook 2's calculations require exercising Macro 2, which is activated by clicking a command button Button 6 in Workbook 2.

The button name is "Button 6" and I know the name of the macro it initializes.

How do I click Button 6 from Macro 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clicking the button in the other workbook run the button's click event function or intended function by using Application.Run method.

Application.Run "workbookName!functionName"

Comment: I tried that. I get Runtime error 1004 - cannot run the macro ____. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled. 

But I know that it is available in wb2 and macros are enabled

Comment: Workbook 2 is supposed to be opened when you call the function.

Comment: And function must be defined as Public.

Comment: Hahah yes wb2 is definitely open.

I don't know whether it's defined as public, but I can't change anything in that workbook. So if it's not defined as public, I can't change that. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Does it mean you don't have source code access for the workbook 2?

Comment: And what is.workbook 2 exact name? contains any spaces in the workbook name?

Comment: If you're just not allowed to change the existing code but you do have access to the VBProject, add a Public Sub which just calls the Private one.

Comment: About the name: if your workbook name contains spaces then you need to enclose the file name with single quotes in the double quotes. Like Application.Run "'FileName.xls'!FunctionName"

Comment: I wasn't adding the single quotes. That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just call the macro directly in the second book that button6 would call.
(The second workbook will need to be open for this code to work)

For example:

```
Application.Run "'Workbook2.xlsm'!Macro2"
```

Comment: I tried that. I get Runtime error 1004 - cannot run the macro ____. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled. But I know that it is available in wb2 and macros are enabled.

Comment: Have you enabled macros in your trust centre and is the second workbook open? If it's not you need to add further code to open and close the second workbook around the application.run line

Comment: Can you do it manually? If so - you should be able to use the macro recorder to get your code...

Answer (score 0):

3 ideas, not tested. Inspired by http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/22555-can-visual-basic-applications-%22click%22-button.html:

1)

```
[workbook2].[worksheet].[button6codename]_Click
```

2)

```
[workbook2].[worksheet].CommandButton2 = vbClick
```

3)

```
[workbook2].[worksheet].CommandButton2 = True

[workbook2].[worksheet].CommandButton2 = vbClick
```

All this using a PUBLIC sub!